How to ensure Gitlab pipeline jobs have unique identifiers?
There's plenty of jobs in my pipeline and creating dependency chains in Gitlab would be overly complicated, so I decided to design some scripts that would take care of launching manual jobs.
I can list jobs defined in my pipeline and I get a list containing objects as e.g.:
{
    "id": 285,
    "status": "success",
    "stage": "build_images",
    "name": "build_variant_d",
    "ref": "random-choice-test",
    "tag": false,
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": true,
    "created_at": "2024-04-15T14:27:28.869Z",
    "started_at": "2024-04-15T14:27:30.311Z",
    "finished_at": "2024-04-15T15:43:00.829Z",
    "duration": 4510.312213,
    "...": "..."
}

Now, I can POST request to this specific job's ID to re-launch the job. However, it gets assigned another ID once it starts, so I can no longer track its status using the initial ID.
Is it possible to give jobs unique identifiers so that they can be re-launched with use of the same identifier over and over?

How about using the built-in environment variable, CI_JOB_NAME?
